# single click text selection in eclipse java editor

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

my eclipse has started to select words as soon as the cursor is somewhere inside the word. used to be the word had to be double clicked to be selected but now it just does it when the cursor is inside a word.
i have no idea if i accidentally changed something but i couldn't find any solution on google so i hope you guys can help.
i find the automatic selection and extremely distracting like this but turning it off completely i also not very desirable so i'm hoping it's a simple setting i was unable to find.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just highlighting the word? If that's the problem, you should see an icon depicting an highlighter above the editor. Just disable that.

Comment: hi Federicio
i don't see a highlighter icon above the editor. all i do is single click into a given word and it will highlight all occurances of that word. yesterday i installed the beyond compare plugin but i didn't find any setting that might affect this behavior there either.

Comment: I'm talking about [this icon](https://i.imgur.com/Qw7WLtK.png)

Comment: that icon is not in my toolbar, it looks deceptively similar to the search icon but its only the search icon that is there in my toolbar. i also tried to restore all the default settings under Window -> Preferences but that did not help either.
for the time being i'll just use alt+shift+o to toggle marking occurrences